# How to add a custom prop to all pages templates in nextjs's App router

Tags: next.js

I want to make a specific dynamic variable & accessible on All pages' props, by using the App Router

By using Pages router, it would've been easier just by implementing **getServerSideProps**, but I really want to keep using the app router instead.

Is there any workaround to achieve the same implementation ?